# Array Index Out Of Bounds When Drawing Pixels

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, render

I'm currently trying to draw pixels to my window and I seem to come across and index out of bounds error when the program starts. I honestly have no idea how to fix it. Can anybody tell me where the problem is? I've checked plenty of times but it seems like it should be just fine to me. I've given all the code for my project below, but the error is on the line in the render method (Game class) where the for loop is.

EDIT:

The error is somewhere in the for loop in the Game class. it says

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48601" at the line
>   "pixles[i] = screen.pixels[i]"

Screen Class

```
public class Screen {
    private int width,height;
    public int[] pixels;

    public Screen(int width,int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height]; 

    }

    public void render(){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                pixels[x + y * width] = 0xff00ff; 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
Game Class
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private int width = 300;
    private int height = width / 16 * 9;
    private int scale = 3;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private JFrame frame;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width * scale, height * scale,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
   private Screen screen;
    public Game(){

        screen = new Screen(width,height);
        frame = new JFrame("Relm Of The Mad God Clone");
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);



        start();

    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        thread = new Thread(this,"Running Thread");
        thread.start(); 
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        try{
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game g = new Game();
    }

    private void update(){

    }

    private void render(){
        BufferStrategy buffer = getBufferStrategy();

        if (buffer == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }  

        screen.render();

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }

        Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),this);

        g.dispose();
        buffer.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){
            update();
            render();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code exactly?

Comment: It says it in the original post, but it's somewhere in the for loop in the Game class. it says "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48601" at the line "pixles[i] = screen.pixels[i]" @MadProgrammer

Comment: Do the two arrays have the same length?   Add a println() that prints out the length of each so you can see.

Comment: They should be the same length because they represent the amount of pixels on a 900/506 pixel Screen. Here are the results of the print statement: Screen pixels array: 48600, Pixels array: 437400 @NormR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `screen` variable is initialized with `new Screen(width, height)`, so it probably has `width*height` pixels. On the other hand, the `pixels` variable is initialized from `image`, which has `width*scale * height*scale` pixels.

Since `scale=3`, this means that the `pixels` array is 3 times longer than the `screen` array. That is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think of that! @Vainolo